# Problems with a signed Mac app on 10.9.5 (even after v2 cert was generated)

Tags: macos, signing

I'm trying to sign a Mac app but i'm having problems on 10.9.5+. I've generated a new v2 certificate (Developer ID), and signed the app with Xcode, and verified that the cert is indeed v2, but i still get the Gatekeeper warning.  I created a brand new test app, thinking maybe some old project setting might have been causing an issue, but same problem.

Here is what codesign tells me about the app (removing some identifying values):

```
codesign -dvvv NewApp.app/

Executable=/Users/XXXXXXXXXXX/Projects/Tests/NewApp/Releases/NewApp.app/Contents/MacOS/NewApp
Identifier=com.XXXXXXXXXXX.NewApp
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=228 flags=0x0(none) hashes=4+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=732ec1e6c4f2ae7b2a0e2da5f92693c27a8cbf0e
Signature size=8523
Authority=Developer ID Application: XXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXXXX)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=Sep 30, 2014, 11:04:31 AM
Info.plist entries=21
TeamIdentifier=SFM7SSUSXP
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=1
Internal requirements count=1 size=216
```

But this is what spectl tells me:

```
spctl -a -t exec -vv --verbose NewApp.app/

NewApp.app/: rejected
source=Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: XXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXXXX)
```

What gives? Is there any other feedback i can dig for that will tell me why its rejected?

[UPDATE}

Not building any frameworks in my app, so these posts suggested below didn't much much. I did come across that RB App Checker app, and ran it against my very simple app (brand new app created with XCode6). I get this result:

```
    Evaluating the application “NewApp”.

The application was signed by “Apple Root CA”, “Developer ID Application: XXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXXX)”.
    Both the verified timestamp and the signing-time are: Oct 2, 2014, 10:50:08 AM.
    The object code format is “bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)”.
    Both bundle and signing identifiers are “ XXXXXXXXXX.NewApp”.
    The signature specifies explicit requirements. ￼
    The signature specifies resource rules (v1). ￼
    The signature specifies resource rules (v2). ￼
    Requirements and resources validate correctly.

The code signature contains 3 certificates. ￼
    Certificate “Apple Root CA”: ￼
        Your keychain contains this trusted root certificate.
        Will expire on Feb 9, 2035.
    Certificate “Developer ID Certification Authority”: ￼
        Will expire on Feb 1, 2027.
    Certificate “Developer ID Application: XXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXXX)”: ￼
        Will expire on Oct 1, 2019.
        SHA1 fingerprint: “XXXXXXXXXX”.

The application is probably from an authorized Apple Developer.

The code signature contains entitlements. ￼

The application is not sandboxed.
```

Is the fact that there is a v1 and v2 resource rule in there causing the issue?

Comment: It's hard to tell from spctl's rejection message here, but if you haven't already, go read Craig Hockenberry's excellent article on [10.9.x code signing](http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/), he gives a lot of good hints.  Daniel Jalkut also has a couple of articles which mirror the approach we use at http://indiestack.com/2014/08/take-this-code-and-sign-it/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and the reason was that my Gatekeeper setting was changed to allow "Mac App store" only.

I think I did this change from command line, while trying various hints from internet and I was not really aware of doing it.

Changing Gatekeeper setting to "Mac App store and identified developers" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved the issue after getting very sparse help from Apple tech support. I happened to catch an off-hand comment in a WWDC video regarding "flat" installers. Looking that up, it seems that you can only sign a flat installer package with the actual Installer Developer ID. If you try to sign a non-flat installer package, you can only sign it with the Application Developer ID, which succeeds, but doesn't actually work with Gatekeeper.

So.... I figured out that my installer was non-flat, cause it was targeting an pretty old OS (10.4). I'm using PackageMaker, and once i set the target OS to be 10.5 or newer, it started building a flat installer package, which i was then able to sign correctly (with the Installer Developer ID).